# How can I check how many times a PDF file had been signed?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, bouncycastle, x509certificate

How can I check how many times a PDF file had been signed, using C# and preferably iTextSharp 5.5.11? I'm open to any other .NET PDF library as long as it does the job.

I would like to choose a PDF file from my hard drive and show on a form how many times the PDF file had been signed.

Showing the certificate source would be a bonus.

Thank you.

Comment: By certificates you mean signatures? Or do you mean X.509 certificates?

Comment: Ok. To operate with PDFs you should use a PDF library. General purpose PDF libraries usually support PDF signatures and have an API to allow you to access information on the signatures in an obvious manner.

Comment: Itext's signature api indeed allows counting the existing signature. If you are talking about itext 7, please be aware that the signing api is in its own module.

Answer (score 2):

Since iText exists both in Java and C# and the [Digital Signatures tutorial for iText](https://itextpdf.com/ru/resources/books/digital-signatures-pdf) was written in the former, I will give the answer in Java and there should be no problem to port it to c#:

One can use `SignatureUtil#getTotalRevisions()` to get the number. It has been designed to give you the number of signatures in the document, or that number plus one if changes were applied after the last time the document was signed.

Please check [C5_01_SignatureIntegrity](https://github.com/itext/i7js-signatures/blob/develop/src/test/java/com/itextpdf/samples/signatures/chapter05/C5_01_SignatureIntegrity.java). Here three documents are processed: the first had been signed, but then modified, the second was signed by four persons and the third had been signed by 4 persons and then modified. SignatureUtil#getTotalRevisions() returns 2, 4 and 5 for them respectively.

The results in the first and the third cases are a bit misleading, but one can use `SignatureUtil#signatureCoversWholeDocument(String)` to check whether the last revision corresponds to the last signing or not.

Comment: Uladzimir used itext 7.x which is a complete rewrite of itext 5 and before. That being said, if you just start with itext, you might want to use the current version 7.x instead of an old 5.x version.

Comment: If you for some reason need to use an old 5.x version, the 5.x example corresponding to the example referenced above is [C5_01_SignatureIntegrity.cs from here](https://git.itextsupport.com/projects/I5NS/repos/tutorial/browse/signatures/chapter5/C5_01_SignatureIntegrity/C5_01_SignatureIntegrity.cs).